# Is there an event in Azure for Windows Virtual Machine being assigned to a user from personal host pool?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine, azure-eventgrid

I'm trying to figure out if Azure Virtual Desktop has an event triggered when a Windows virtual machine is assigned to a user from personal host pool.

I will use this information to trigger new virtual machine deployment when the event occurs using Azure automation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such event we have to notify when the user is assigned to session host in host pool.

Comment: At the moment I have created automation that can be scheduled and it will check if there is session hosts in the host pool that aren't assigned to a user. If there are less than 1 session host available it will provision new hosts to the pool.

I want the logic to be smarter and the automation would start when one or more session host gets assigned to a user.